# Who is the Amyrtaios of Herodotus?

Tags: egypt, chronology

In Herodotus it reads the following of Anoosis, the blind pharoah, and Amyrtaios, a pharaoh living over 700 years after him:

> ... when the Ethiopian had gone away out of Egypt, the blind man came
>   back from the fen-country and began to rule again, having lived there
>   during fifty years upon an island which he had made by heaping up
>   ashes and earth: for whenever any of the Egyptians visited him
>   bringing food, according as it had been appointed to them severally to
>   do without the knowledge of the Ethiopian, he bade them bring also
>   some ashes for their gift.
>       This island none was able to find before Amyrtaios; that is, for more than seven hundred years the kings who arose before Amyrtaios
>   were not able to find it. Now the name of this island is Elbo, and its
>   size is ten furlongs each way. **Herodotus, Book II**

The problem is, who is Amyrtaios? According to official Egyptian history he is [Amyrtaeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amyrtaeus), a Saitic rebel who resisted Persian rule for 5 years between 404 and 399 BC. The problem with this is that this Amyrtaeus would not have been born yet when Herodotus was writing about him.

Now, Herodotus says Moeris lived 900 years before himself and Amyrtaeus lived 700 years after Anysis who lived approximately 150-200 years after Moeris, therefore, Herodotus must have considered Amyrtaeus to be roughly contemporaneous with himself.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out. Amyrtaeus the Pharoah had a grandfather named Amyrtaeus who participated in the Inaros Rebellion and ruled the Western Delta from Sau for some time about 25 years before Herodotus and this is the person being referred to.